# How to measure peak load (requests per minute)?

Tags: performance, testing, load

I am trying to measure peak load for some API. I have logs where logged end of request and elapsed time. For now I use only fact 'request end' and do not take into account 'elapsed time'.

But there is problem: the smaller interval I choose to measure RPM, the biggest RPM values are.

Simple example: logs contains single request during last hour. RPM = 1/60 = 0.0167
Select smaller interval - 1ms. All intervals will has RPM = 0, except one that will has RPM = 1*60*1000 = 60000.

How I should select interval to calculate adequate metric? Or may be other metrics can be calculated for measure peak load?